# Spring boot 2.0.3.RELEASE, Spring data rest, application error, failed to start

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-rest

Unable to start spring boot application.

Repository and its associated domain

```
import com.vircosolutions.mobileapi.domain.Awards;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;

@RepositoryRestResource(exported = false)
public interface AwardsRepository extends JpaRepository<Integer, 
Awards> {
}
```

Domain

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date; 
import java.util.Objects;

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "awards")
public class Awards implements Serializable {


private static final long serialVersionUID = -170576994834461289L;


@Id
@Column(name = "id_awards", nullable = false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id_user", nullable = false)
private Users user;

@Column (name = "rating", nullable = false)
private float rating;

@Column (name = "award_type", nullable = false)
private String awardType;

@Column (name = "award_date", nullable = false)
private Date awardDate;

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    Awards awards = (Awards) o;
    return id == awards.id &&
            Float.compare(awards.rating, rating) == 0 &&
            Objects.equals(user, awards.user) &&
            Objects.equals(awardType, awards.awardType) &&
            Objects.equals(awardDate, awards.awardDate);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {

    return Objects.hash(id, user, rating, awardType, awardDate);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Awards{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", user=" + user +
            ", rating=" + rating +
            ", awardType='" + awardType + '\'' +
            ", awardDate=" + awardDate +
            '}';
}
```

}

Main application file looks like

```
@EnableSpringDataWebSupport
@SpringBootApplication
public class MobileApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return super.configure(builder);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MobileApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

I debugged a lot but unable to find out the root cause. Stach trace is given below. If you need any other file and code it can be provided. Any help will be highly appreciated.

> ```
> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. 2018-11-22
> ```
>
> 16:30:35,341 ERROR method: [main] boot.SpringApplication
>   (SpringApplication.java:842) - Application run failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'repositorySearchController' defined in
>   URL
>   [jar:file:/home/rashid/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-rest-webmvc/3.0.8.RELEASE/spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/RepositorySearchController.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'pagedResourcesAssembler' defined in class
>   path resource
>   [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [org.springframework.data.web.PagedResourcesAssembler]:
>   Factory method 'pagedResourcesAssembler' threw exception; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'pageableResolver' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.data.web.PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver]:
>   Factory method 'pageableResolver' threw exception; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'sortResolver' defined in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.data.web.HateoasSortHandlerMethodArgumentResolver]:
>   Factory method 'sortResolver' threw exception; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'repositoryRestConfiguration' defined in class
>   path resource
>   [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.data.rest.core.config.RepositoryRestConfiguration]:
>   Factory method 'repositoryRestConfiguration' threw exception; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'repositories' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories]: Factory
>   method 'repositories' threw exception; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'awardsRepository': Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a
>   managed type: class java.lang.Integer     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:732)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:197)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1276)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1133)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]     at
>   com.vircosolutions.mobileapi.MobileApplication.main(MobileApplication.java:19)
>   [classes/:?] Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'pagedResourcesAssembler' defined in class
>   path resource
>   [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [org.springframework.data.web.PagedResourcesAssembler]:
>   Factory method 'pagedResourcesAssembler' threw exception; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'pageableResolver' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.data.web.PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver]:
>   Factory method 'pageableResolver' threw exception; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'sortResolver' defined in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.data.web.HateoasSortHandlerMethodArgumentResolver]:
>   Factory method 'sortResolver' threw exception; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'repositoryRestConfiguration' defined in class
>   path resource
>   [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.data.rest.core.config.RepositoryRestConfiguration]:
>   Factory method 'repositoryRestConfiguration' threw exception; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'repositories' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories]: Factory
>   method 'repositories' threw exception; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'awardsRepository': Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a
>   managed type: class java.lang.Integer     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:590)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]

Comment: Updated your question: remove the POM and post the code of AwardsRepository and its associated Entity. I am guessing you have reversed the order of the generic arguments declaration.

Comment: @AlanHay updated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have specified the generic types in the wrong order hence the error `Not a managed type: class java.lang.Integer`

Try:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(exported = false)
public interface AwardsRepository extends JpaRepository<Awards, Integer> {
}
```

As an aside, and in line with naming conventions, you should also rename you entity Awards to Award and rename the repository accordingly.

Comment: Like seriously. I think I need to rest now and stop coding go to sleep right now. Anyway thanks man, you saved me.